# When K-shell X-ray is emitted, how the vacancy in the L-shell are filled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, condensed-matter, nuclear-physics, x-rays

When there is a vacancy in the K-shell because of electron capture or incoming energy, an electron in the higher energy level will fill the vacancy and emit a characteristic X-ray. However, I think this will create another vacancy at a higher level, let's say L-shell. Consequently, to fill the vacancy of the L-shell, another electron from the M-shell or higher energy level will come down until it reaches the valence electron. This means that every time K-shell electron capture occurs, all the other transitions (L->K, M->L ...) will occur.

This seems to be not true because we measure much fewer L-shell and M-shell X-rays than K-shell X-rays in the electron capture experiment.

Could somebody explain what happens to the vacancy in the L-shell after an electron goes down to the K-shell?

Comment: Well, yes, to become neutral it will pick up an electron from somewhere else…

Comment: Do you have a particular experimental data set in mind that shows this?

Comment: At first, I considered the experiment as (https://journals.aps.org/prc/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevC.3.172). I realized that actually, this measurement not only measures the x ray but also the Auger electrons. In conclusion, we indeed have to pick up an electron from somewhere else as Jon Custer said, and this happens like a cascade, but not all of the energy is emitted by x-ray.

Answer (score 1):

There are two competing processes here. The excited atom may emit a fluorescent photon, or it may dump energy by emitting an Auger electron. The [fluorescent yield](https://www.nist.gov/system/files/documents/2018/03/26/jpcrd473.pdf) is the probability that it emits a photon. Outer shell vacancies have a lower fluorescent yield than inner shell vacancies: they are more likely to de-excite via the Auger process.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helps a lot.